# Jquery regular expression in the following format a1xxxxyy

Tags: jquery, regex

```
function validateregex() {
    var testreg = $("#txtregex").val();
    filter = /^[b1]{2}[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9][0-9]{2}$/;
    var regExp = new RegExp(filter);
    if (regExp.test(testreg)) {
        alert("valid");
    }
}
```

8 characters in length, should start with a1, x can be of any character, y can be of any number

Comment: Its better you write what are valid inputs.

Comment: @anubhava: something like in this format a1abcd12

Comment: @user3080252: You can use this regex: `/^[a-z]1[a-z]{4}[0-9]{2}$/i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
/^a(?:1(?:[a-z]{4}(?:[0-9]{2})?)?)?$/i
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/hX4aF2)

This works If you want to match strings like you said :

```
a
a1 
a1abcd
a1abcd99
```

Comment: well it should be like, it should accept in the following way...a,a1,a1abcd,a1abcd99

Comment: You should of made that clear on your question, please edit it and state exactly what your desired output should be.

Comment: this is the answer: filter = /^[a1]{0,2}[a-zA-Z]{0,4}[0-9]{0,2}$/;

Comment: your above answer also doesn't solve the issue...you can try out with my solution /^[a1]{0,2}[a-zA-Z]{0,4}[0-9]{0,2}$/ this will give the exact result

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^a(1([a-z]{4}([0-9]{2})?)?)?$/i
```

It should return TRUE for these strings:

```
a
a1
a1abcd
a1abcd99
```

And it should return FALSE for these:

```
aabcd
a199
a1abc99
a1abcd9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
/^a1\w{4}\d{2}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a1]{0,2}[a-zA-Z]{0,4}[0-9]{0,2}$/
```